# How to add qt resources to android APK file?

Tags: android, c++, qt, cross-platform

I'm porting a small `Qt` application to the `Android`. I am using **Qt Creator**.

I have a resource file with some images. The question is how to add these files to the android *APK package*.
Another question is how to access them from `Qt`?
Can I use something like:

> QIcon actions_ok = QIcon(RES_PATH + "check.png")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add the images to your `assets` folder, and then access them using the following URI:

```
file:///android_asset/check.png
```

Comment: What is the assets folder? In a necessitas Qt editor I can see only android/res and android/src/org/kde/necessitas.

Comment: The assets folder is part of the standard APK structure and a sibling of the `res` folder. The Android OS provides a special URI format as shown above to access it.

Comment: Ok, and how to add this directory to APK in Necessitas?