# How to use QFile on Android?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qtcore

I need read .txt file on android using qt program. If build for windows, that file should be in build folder, but what about android? How to include it in apk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the text file into your APK's assets, and then refer to it like so:

```
QFile file( "assets:/qml/foo/main.qml" );
```

This question has another URI for accessing assets: [How to add qt resources to android APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071161/how-to-add-qt-resources-to-android-apk-file?rq=1)

Or you can package the QFile in your application as a QRC (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/resources.html) and access it like so:

```
QFile file( "qrc:/path/to/file.abc" );
```

Both of these options are read only.

Comment: Thank you, but if I write this QFile file( "assets:/qml/foo/main.qml" );compile and run and add file to apk: res/assets/qml/, after start program file will empty.

Comment: It should be in 'assets', not in the 'res/assets' directory. The assets folder sits at the same level as the res folder.